# Функция-подписчик на контент (React, TS)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Поставили задачу создать функцию, которая раз в определенное время будет ходить по определенному get запросу (axios) и тянуть данные. Не пойму, как сделать её, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку (допустим, "Открыть смену") она начинала своё действия, а по нажатию (допустим "Закрыть смену") - прекращала и при этом в случае ошибки самовозобновлялась.

Буду благодарен за подсказку/ решение с более-менее подробным описанием :)

Comment: Использовать API броузера, например `setTimeout` и `clearTimeout`. Желательно локализировать проблему, а так это слишком общий вопрос.

Comment: Подсмотрите здесь: [Старт и остановка таймера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460161/1460172#1460172) или [здесь для React](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1472830/1472845#1472845)